# How to make my code that has while/for/if loop more efficient in R

Tags: r, performance, time, nested-loops, distance

My code (shown below) takes each row in the dataframe and assigns it to a group based on time and distance criteria. The group is based on numerical identifiers in a new column. It doesn't take too long to process <80k observations, but unfortunately some of my data is much larger than that. Is there any way I can restructure my code to cut run time? I know nested if/for loops are not the best. I vectorized what I could (I think), and I know taking conditions out of for loop helps but now sure how to do it. Code below for reference. There's also an output of the data after the code. Any tips are greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
#counter
j <- 1

#create a new empty column, set first row value to 1
df$Group <- NA
df$Group[1] <- 1

#while the new column has NAs, rerun this loop
while (any(is.na(df$Group))==TRUE) {

#for row 2 to last
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {

  #find the first row with NA
  if(is.na(df$Group[i])==TRUE){

  #get coordinates of recently grouped points IDd in new column
  getGroup <- df[which(df$Group==max(df$Group))]
  groupLoc <- cbind(getGroup$Long,getGroup$Lat)

  #get coordinates of row with NA
  pointLoc <- cbind(df$Long[i],df$Lat[i])

  
  #get most recent time of grouped points IDd in new column
  lastrow <- tail(getGroup, n = 1)

  #get time of row with NA
  moment <- lastrow$DateTime
  
  #if time difference <15min and distance <16km between group and new point, add point to current group by assigning same numerical ID, otherwise keep it at NA
  ifelse (min(spDistsN1(groupLoc,pointLoc,longlat = TRUE))<16 & 
          difftime(df$DateTime[i],moment)<minutes(15),
          df$Group[i] <-j,df$Group[i] <-NA)
}
#increase counter to create a new group
j=j+1
}
```

The first loop of my data looks like this:

```r
DateTime             Lat    Long    Group  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.482  81.066   1  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.475  81.085   1  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.484  81.084   1  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.492  81.080   1  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.494  81.078   NA   
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.493  81.080   1  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.495  81.075   NA  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.493  81.081   1  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.497  81.075   NA  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.807  81.074   NA
```

The finished loop of my data looks like this:

```r
DateTime             Lat    Long    Group  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.482  81.066   1  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.475  81.085   1  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.484  81.084   1  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.492  81.080   1  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.494  81.078   2   
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.493  81.080   1  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.495  81.075   2  
2019-07-01 00:00:04  28.493  81.081   1  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.497  81.075   2  
2019-07-01 00:16:04  28.807  81.074   3
```

Comment: Code is tough to digest. Can you edit post and plainly describe in text how `GroupId` is calculated? In fact what does this column signify? Wouldn't you need to order rows by column(s)? I see comparison of distance and coordinates from previous row for cumulative counts.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be called GroupId, I changed it to Group. It is the new column I created, and basically, that new column starts out as empty(NA), with only the first row having the value 1. You go through each row and if the two conditions (distance and time) are met, it will get the value 1 (belong to group 1). If condition is not met, the row value stays at NA.

Comment: Once it's at the end of the row, the group # increments to two and while loop checks if the group column still has empty values (NA), if it does, it runs through again and fills the remaining NA if it meets the condition. Process keeps going until there are no more empty (NA) values in the Group column.

Comment: What does *Group* signify? Group of what? It appears dependent on unordered rows which are important since rows decide distance and time comparison. Are there other columns not shown here. In other words, what is difference of `Group == 1` and `Group == 2`. With better context, we may help refactor your code. This seens like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) where you ask help on your *y* solution but not *x* problem.

Comment: Each row gets placed in a group (1,2,..,n) based on the following: In the for loop, each row is compared to a group of rows (starting off, the first group will only have the first row in it, with Group value of "1"). If the 2nd row is within 15 min and 16km of the group, it will be included in that group (i.e. get the group value 1) but if not, it's group value stays empty. Let's say it met the criteria. Now row 2 is in the group.

Comment: Then in the next loop, row 3 will be checked if it belongs to the group (which now has rows 1 and 2). The process iterates to include or exclude rows from the group and when you get to the end, the while loop checks if there are any rows that have an empty group value. If there is then the for loop starts again, but increments the group counter so the next group will have a value of 2 and so on...